# WCF: how to generate a single WSDL document, without WSDL:import?

Tags: wcf, web-services, wsdl, namespaces

I'm troubling into an issue...
I'm trying to find a way to generate a single wsdl document from my WCF service, i.e. without any link to external documents.
I've used [FlatWsdl](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/0e947743-2d0f-4a8d-8922-2a7c1e70f56f) to remove all xsd:import links, bou my generated wsdl still contains a link to an external wsdl document via a wsdl:import declaration:

```
<wsdl:import namespace="http://myurl/mynamespace"  
             location="http://myserver/myservice.svc?wsdl=wsdl0"/>
```

This document actually contains all inlined xsd schemas, so... there's a way to inline also this external wsdl document, in order to have a single wsdl?

Thanks a lot for any kind of help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

(EDIT: Previous answer about FlatWSDL deleted, because as you pointed out it was about eliminating xsd:import not wsdl:import.)

Look at this blogpost: [Control generated WSDL in WCF](http://www.pluralsight.com/community/blogs/kirillg/archive/2006/06/18/28380.aspx)

"... There is always one WSDL generated for one target namespace URI ..."

Do you have different namespace for ServiceContract, DataContract, ServiceBehavior, etc. ?

Comment: You can also add this as a behavior to a service using the standard service host factory - see my links.

Comment: I've used FlatWsdl, but this flattening only xsd:import and not wsdl:import... maybe I've made a mistake, but looking at the code only XSD are changed :(

Comment: that link is dead, here it is via waybackmachine: http://web.archive.org/web/20100723044037/http://www.pluralsight-training.net/community/blogs/kirillg/archive/2006/06/18/28380.aspx

Comment: the root cause is explained in the above link, the simplest way to resolve this issue is using ?singlewsdl.

Comment: Copy of the dead link: https://viviendo20.wordpress.com/2017/02/15/control-generated-wsdl-in-wcf-namespaces/

Answer (score 22):

You can now do this natively in .net 4.5 (beta). There is an option (?singleWsdl instead of ?wsdl) for telling the service to output everything in a single wsdl document. More info on the new stuff here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456789(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4):

You could also use the WCFExtras project it has an extension to create a single WSDL-file.

> **WCFExtras**
>
> A collection of useful WCF extensions
>   including Soap Header support, WSDL
>   documentation and more.
>
> The WCF platform is very extensible
>   and allows you to easily add features
>   that are not part of the core product.
>   This project contains some extensions
>   I needed in a WCF based project:
>
> - SOAP Header support for WCF Adding WSDL
> - Documentation from Source Code XML Comments
> - Override SOAP Address Location URL
> - Single WSDL file for better compatibility with older SOAP tools.

http://wcfextras.codeplex.com/

Comment: I've take a look at WCFExtras, but from my investigations (maybe I'm wrong) the feature "Single WSDL file" inlines XSD's but not external WSDL's... 
maybe my problem is here: "... There is always one WSDL generated for one target namespace URI ..." as suggested from Vizu

Answer (score 2):

my problem was in endpoint definitions, that are in tempuri.org namespace
adding bindingNamespace to endpoint declarations fix my problem.
thanks to all for help :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a late answer, but I had the same problem with a few of our WCF services.  If you're on .NET 4.5, like the earlier answer, use ?singleWSDL, but if you're not targeting .NET 4.5 then I added the following to my web.config to fix the issue...

```
<useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
  <defaultPorts>
    <add port="80" scheme="http" />
    <add port="443" scheme="https" />
  </defaultPorts>
</useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
```

This goes in your behavior.  That way I didn't have to flatten the WSDL because all references were to MyURL instead of MyServer.

Hope this helps others with a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Jim's answer above, if you're using C# code to configure a WCF ServiceHost directly:

```
using System.ServiceModel.Configuration;
```

and when setting up your ServiceHost:

```
UseRequestHeadersForMetadataAddressBehavior urh = new UseRequestHeadersForMetadataAddressBehavior();
serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(urh);
```

I struggled to find this information online, as simple as it is. Hopefully helps someone in a similar situation.