# Generate WSDL web-service objects in SAP

Tags: wcf, soap, wsdl, webservice-client, sap-basis

is it possible with SAP to generate client stubs and transfer objects from a WSDL served by a .NET WCF web service? Or do I have to build my SOAP XML requests manually?

To be more on the point. I still have a WCF web service and the wsdl. I have no knowlege in SAP. So the question is. Is it possible and how can I create client service stubs and the transfer objects in SAP from my WSDL?

Comment: Why don't you try? A little effort from you saves a lot for others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy to create an ABAP client for an existing web service if you have access to the URL for obtaining the wsdl file or the wsdl file itself. See this [link](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/index?rid=/library/uuid/6066fbe8-edc4-2910-9584-a9601649747d&overridelayout=true) for an step by step tutorial wich is basically: 
  1- Generate proxy from wsdl using assitant
  2- Use proxy generated in your ABAP program

Regards

Answer (score 2):

You can use the WSDL from the wcf for this. You can get the WSDL as `service.svc?wsdl`. However at times, some SOAP client generator expect all the definitions of the SOAP/WSDL in a single call. For that you might have to look at the following pages:

1. http://weblogs.asp.net/pglavich/archive/2010/03/16/making-wcf-output-a-single-wsdl-file-for-interop-purposes.aspx
2. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/f03b6e78-ef28-4692-8f19-62d2f2d3bc9c
3. [WCF: how to generate a single WSDL document, without WSDL:import?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985320/wcf-how-to-generate-a-single-wsdl-document-without-wsdlimport)