# How to generate wsdl without imports

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

When I create a webservice with wcf the generated wsdl contains import statements which reference to another site.
The problem is that the client that is supposed to consume this webservice can't handle such imports.

Is it possible to include the definitions of the import directly in the main wsdl so the client only has to load this single wsdl file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985320/wcf-how-to-generate-a-single-wsdl-document-without-wsdlimport). Another useful [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/pglavich/archive/2010/03/16/making-wcf-output-a-single-wsdl-file-for-interop-purposes.aspx)

Comment: Take a look at http://weblogs.asp.net/pglavich/archive/2010/03/16/making-wcf-output-a-single-wsdl-file-for-interop-purposes.aspx